# How to set rtl in table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my css I use:

```
body {
    font-weight: 300;
    direction: rtl;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Also in html I use:

```
<body dir="rtl">
```

I have a table bootstrap table like this:

```
<table align="center" class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 25%">کد عضویت</td>
      <td>426075</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>نام</td>
      <td>سوسن</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But all my writings are still left aligned instead of right aligned, regardless I used rtl. A full source codepen and page view is at: https://codepen.io/joehark/pen/yLLeyoG

What mistake I did and how to right aligned my table writings? Do I still need `class="text-justify"` within each `<td>`? If yes, what is the purpose of that rtl setting at all?

Comment: td {text-align: right;}?

Comment: The rtl actually reverses the order in which the columns appear

Comment: So do I still need `class="text-justify"` regardless rtl setting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `direction:rtl` is not enough since it affect the align of block elements:

> The property sets the base text direction of block-level elements and
>   the direction of embeddings created by the unicode-bidi property. It
>   also sets the default alignment of text, block-level elements, and the
>   direction that cells flow within a table row.
>   Unlike the dir attribute in HTML, the direction property is not
>   inherited from table columns into table cells, since CSS inheritance
>   follows the document tree, and table cells are inside of rows but not
>   inside of columns.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/direction)

Use: `td {text-align: right; direction: rtl;}` in order to set right align text on table's td.